# Single class imported in two seperate places issue

Tags: python

In Python, I have a "data" class defined that holds as a class variable some deseralized data, and a load() @classmethod that loads the data from disk and stores it in the class variable.

Like so:

```
class_a.py
class ClassA(object):
  data = None

  @classmethod
  def load(cls):
    ...
    cls.data = ...
```

Now I import this in two places:

1) Jupyter notebook
2) In another file that is imported by the jupyter notebook (helper.py)

However, the issue is when I first call ClassA.load() in the jupyter notebook, I then call a method imported from helper.py that calls on ClassA, and I get an error where ClassA.data is None.

In the jupyter notebook, I can access ClassA.data like normal after I call ClassA.load(). When I call the function in helper.py which uses ClassA.data, it gives me an error. **Investigating further, the memory address of ClassA in the jupyter notebook is different than the address in helper.py**.

Is this expected? I feel like I am running into something about classes that I don't understand. I thought if you define a class, that is stored at only one place in memory.

Comment: Sounds like you've screwed up your imports and created two `class_a` modules from the same file. This is a very common problem.

Comment: Importing the same file twice is normally fine and normally doesn't create duplicate modules, but if you've screwed up your import path such that the same file is visible two ways, importing it both ways will create two modules.

Comment: That was it. I was appending to the pythonpath w/ sys.path.append in the jupyter notebook. Not doing this fixed the imports